# Issue while building netty from source

Tags: java, maven, compilation, netty

When I build netty from source, the build fails at

> [INFO] Netty/Transport/Native/Epoll ....................... FAILURE [  5.927 s]

The Error message that I get is

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.fusesource.hawtjni:maven-hawtjni-plugin:1.10:build (build-native-lib) on project netty-transport-native-epoll: build failed: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Extracted package did not look like it contained a native source build. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to compile a native library, to do so you should be under Linux and have additional libraries installed from http://netty.io/wiki/native-transports.html.