# Compiling netty-tcnative dll for Windows 32-bit not working

Tags: dll, netty

I am unable to compile the netty tcnative dll for Windows 32-bit. I have followed the guide on the netty site on how to build, and all of the steps succeed except the maven install.

This is the log for that step:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: windows
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: windows-x86_64
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [Parent]
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [OpenSSL - Dynamic]
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [OpenSSL - Static]
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [BoringSSL - Static]
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [LibreSSL - Static]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Netty/TomcatNative [Parent] 2.0.7.Final-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3:enforce (enforce-maven) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3:enforce (enforce-tools) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:check (check-style) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (write-version-properties) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] Current commit: 372b3e3 on 2017-09-12 10:15:57 -0700
   [delete] Deleting: c:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\target\classes\META-INF\io.netty.versions.properties
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: c:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\target\classes\META-INF\io.netty.versions.properties
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (native-manifest) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] Bundle-NativeCode: META-INF/native/netty_tcnative.dll;osname=win32;processor=x86_64
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (copy-src) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (build-apr) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

build-apr:
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.9:check (default) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] Signature checking is skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0:manifest (generate-manifest) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[WARNING] Ignoring project type pom - supportedProjectTypes = [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources-no-fork) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ netty-tcnative-parent ---
[INFO] Installing c:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\pom.xml to C:\Users\Rudi\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-tcnative-parent\2.0.7.Final-SNAPSHOT\netty-tcnative-parent-2.0.7.Final-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Netty/TomcatNative [OpenSSL - Dynamic] 2.0.7.Final-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3:enforce (enforce-maven) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3:enforce (enforce-tools) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3:enforce (enforce-msbuild-environment) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10:check (check-style) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (write-version-properties) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] Current commit: 372b3e3 on 2017-09-12 10:15:57 -0700
   [delete] Deleting: C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\classes\META-INF\io.netty.versions.properties
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\classes\META-INF\io.netty.versions.properties
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (native-manifest) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] Bundle-NativeCode: META-INF/native/netty_tcnative.dll;osname=win32;processor=x86_64
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (copy-src) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (build-apr) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

build-apr:
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hawtjni-plugin:1.11:generate (build-native-lib) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-hawtjni-plugin:1.11:build (build-native-lib) @ netty-tcnative ---
[INFO] executing: cmd.exe /X /C "msbuild vs2010.vcxproj /property:Platform=x64 /property:Configuration=release"
[INFO] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.21005.1
[INFO] [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
[INFO] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Build started 9/15/2017 1:26:35 PM.
[INFO] Project "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
[INFO] InitializeBuildStatus:
[INFO]   Touching "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\netty_tcnative.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
[INFO] ClCompile:
[INFO]   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include" /I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include\win32" /I"C:\Workspaces\apr-1.5.2-dist\include" /I"C:\Workspaces\apr-1.5.2-dist\include\arch\win32" /I"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include" /I"C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\\src\windows" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Ot /GL /D WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /D WIN64 /D NDEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D HAVE_OPENSSL /D _WINDLL /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR- /Fo"C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\\" /Fd"C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue .\src\bb.c .\src\error.c .\src\jnilib.c .\src\native_constants.c .\src\ssl.c .\src\sslcontext.c .\src\sslutils.c
[INFO]   bb.c
[INFO]   error.c
[INFO]   jnilib.c
[INFO] .\src\jnilib.c(75): warning C4267: 'function' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'jsize', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\jnilib.c(77): warning C4267: 'function' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'jsize', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\jnilib.c(251): warning C4090: '=' : different 'const' qualifiers [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   native_constants.c
[INFO]   ssl.c
[INFO] .\src\ssl.c(314): warning C4267: 'function' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\ssl.c(1261): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\ssl.c(1321): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   sslcontext.c
[INFO] .\src\sslcontext.c(859): warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\sslcontext.c(881): warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\sslcontext.c(952): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\sslcontext.c(970): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\sslcontext.c(994): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\sslcontext.c(1185): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] .\src\sslcontext.c(1333): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   sslutils.c
[INFO] Link:
[INFO]   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/lib\netty_tcnative.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Workspaces\apr-1.5.2-dist\lib" Psapi.lib Shlwapi.lib Ws2_32.lib "libapr-1.lib" ssleay32.lib libeay32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/lib\netty_tcnative.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/lib\netty_tcnative.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /DLL "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\bb.obj"
[INFO]   "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\error.obj"
[INFO]   "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\jnilib.obj"
[INFO]   "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\native_constants.obj"
[INFO]   "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\ssl.obj"
[INFO]   "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\sslcontext.obj"
[INFO]   "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/obj\sslutils.obj"
[INFO]      Creating library C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/lib\netty_tcnative.lib and object C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/lib\netty_tcnative.exp
[INFO] error.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_vsnprintf [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] error.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_strerror [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] jnilib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_version_string [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] jnilib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_version [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
(and many similar lines of errors)
[INFO] ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_SESSION_set_timeout [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
(and many similar lines of errors)
[INFO] sslcontext.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv23_method [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] sslcontext.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
(and many similar lines of errors)
[INFO] sslutils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_get_ex_data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] sslutils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_get_ex_new_index [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
(and many similar lines of errors)
[INFO] C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/lib\netty_tcnative.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 185 unresolved externals [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] Done Building Project "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Build FAILED.
[INFO] 
[INFO] "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
[INFO] (ClCompile target) -> 
[INFO]   .\src\jnilib.c(75): warning C4267: 'function' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'jsize', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\jnilib.c(77): warning C4267: 'function' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'jsize', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\jnilib.c(251): warning C4090: '=' : different 'const' qualifiers [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\ssl.c(314): warning C4267: 'function' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\ssl.c(1261): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\ssl.c(1321): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\sslcontext.c(859): warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\sslcontext.c(881): warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\sslcontext.c(952): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\sslcontext.c(970): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\sslcontext.c(994): warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'jlong' to 'long', possible loss of data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\sslcontext.c(1185): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   .\src\sslcontext.c(1333): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] "C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
[INFO] (Link target) -> 
[INFO]   error.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_vsnprintf [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   error.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_strerror [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   jnilib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_version_string [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   jnilib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_version [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   jnilib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_atomic_init [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   jnilib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_pool_create_ex [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   jnilib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_initialize [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   jnilib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_apr_terminate [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_SESSION_set_timeout [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
(and many similar lines of errors)
[INFO]   sslcontext.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv23_method [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   sslcontext.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
(and many similar lines of errors)
[INFO]   sslutils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_get_ex_data [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO]   sslutils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSL_get_ex_new_index [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
(and many similar lines of errors)
[INFO]   C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\/target/x64-release/lib\netty_tcnative.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 185 unresolved externals [C:\Workspaces\netty-tcnative\openssl-dynamic\target\native-build\vs2010.vcxproj]
[INFO] 
[INFO]     13 Warning(s)
[INFO]     186 Error(s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] Time Elapsed 00:00:02.28
[INFO] rc: 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [Parent] ........................ SUCCESS [  4.724 s]
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [OpenSSL - Dynamic] ............. FAILURE [  5.096 s]
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [OpenSSL - Static] .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [BoringSSL - Static] ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Netty/TomcatNative [LibreSSL - Static] ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.427 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-15T13:26:38+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/224M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.fusesource.hawtjni:maven-hawtjni-plugin:1.11:build (build-native-lib) on project netty-tcnative: build failed: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: vcbuild failed with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :netty-tcnative
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because sharing files doesn't fit into the stackexchange question & answer format, because files will get outdated often, this because every update to the upstream project basically means that the files get outdated. Try manually compiling the required file "netty-tcnative.dll" using the project instructions for this, and post a more direct question using the errors you get. This also helps to compile future versions of the library by yourself.

Comment: Apologies, updated my request.

Comment: Hi there, should I create a new request containing the updated version of this question or is there another way to get it out of the "on hold" status?

Comment: Are you referring to apache maven? if so, it might be useful to include that tag for people who follow it.

Comment: Seems related https://stackoverflow.com/q/36429663/5292302, maybe duplicate